# SQL update from one table to another table based on an id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration, ef-core-2.1

I have a database with 2 tables - `Employees` and `Group`.

The `Employees` has these columns:

```
Id (primary key), Name, GroupId
```

`Group` has these columns:

```
Id (primary key), EmployeeId (foreign key), GroupId
```

This is the `Employees` table:

```
+-----+------+---------+
| Id  | Name | GroupId |
+-----+------+---------+
| 123 | abc  | 000     |
| 456 | def  | 000     |
+-----+------+---------+
```

And this is the `Group` table:

```
+-----+------------+---------+
| Id  | EmployeeId | GroupId |
+-----+------------+---------+
| pqr | 456        | g01     |
| uvw | 123        | g02     |
| xyz | 123        | g03     |
+-----+------------+---------+
```

I need to get any one `GroupId` (for example top one) of an `EmployeeId` from `Group` table and update `GroupId` in `Employees` table.

The final result should like this:

```
+-----+------+---------+
| Id  | Name | GroupId |
+-----+------+---------+
| 123 | abc  | g01     |
| 456 | def  | g02     |
+-----+------+---------+
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions on the same. Thanks!

I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `cross apply`:

```
update e
    set groupid = g.groupid
    from employees e cross apply
         (select top (1) g.*
          from groups g
          where e.employeeid = g.employeeid
         ) g;
```

It seems strange to update `employees` with an *arbitrary* `groupid`.  If you want one in particular -- such as the oldest -- you can add an `order by` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

#### This query will update Employee table from Group table and PK of group table is integer

```
UPDATE e
   SET GroupId = g.GroupId
  FROM Employees e INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT EmployeeId, GroupId FROM [Group] ORDER BY Id DESC) g 
        ON e.Id = g.EmployeeId
```